# how to select only one checkbox using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I am using checkbox in the asp.net gridview. I want select only one checkbox at time. if I select one checkbox other checkboxes should be deselected.

I have html view source

```
<input id="ctl00_MainContent_mGrid_ob_mGridBodyContainer_ctl02_ctl02_ctl00_ChkID" type="checkbox" 
<input id="ctl00_MainContent_mGrid_ob_mGridBodyContainer_ctl03_ctl02_ctl00_ChkID" type="checkbox"
```

Comment: Maybe you want to use radio button instead?

Comment: Do you have 2 checkboxes by row? I agree that a radiobutton is better for this case though.

Answer (score 4):

Usually radio buttons are used for the exclusive functionality where only one item in a group is selected and the browser will do taht for you automatically with the right HTML.

For checkboxes, you could code it with jQuery like this:

```
<div class="checkboxContainer">
    <input id="ctl00_MainContent_mGrid_ob_mGridBodyContainer_ctl02_ctl02_ctl00_ChkID" type="checkbox"> Item 1<br>
    <input id="ctl00_MainContent_mGrid_ob_mGridBodyContainer_ctl03_ctl02_ctl00_ChkID" type="checkbox"> Item 2<br>
    <input id="ctl00_MainContent_mGrid_ob_mGridBodyContainer_ctl04_ctl02_ctl00_ChkID" type="checkbox"> Item 3
</div>​

$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    $(this).closest(".checkboxContainer").find("input[type='checkbox']").not(this).prop("checked", false);
    $(this).prop("checked", true);
});
```

​
Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/hWEXx/

Here's the pure HTML way of doing exclusive radio buttons (also in that same demo):

```
<div class="radioGroup">
    <input type="radio" name="group1">Item A<br>
    <input type="radio" name="group1">Item B<br>
    <input type="radio" name="group1">Item C<br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a radio button instead of a checkbox.

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="parents" value="Mom" /> Mom<br />
    <input type="radio" name="parents" value="Dad" /> Dad
</form>
```

Comment: This is indeed the kind of situation radio buttons were *made* for.  Besides the extra work required to make checkboxes act like you want, radio buttons are more semantically correct -- their very existence is a visual clue that "hey, you can only pick one of these" -- and they'll do the right thing even if for some reason JavaScript is disabled.

Comment: Besides radio buttons being the natural fit for the job. You bring up a great point in regard to the possibility of JavaScript being disabled.

Answer (score 0):

in asp.net you should use radiobuttons instead checkboxes (in this case)

```
<div class="group">
   <asp:RadioButton Id="radio1" runat="server" GroupName="radioGroup" />
   <asp:RadioButton Id="radio2" runat="server" GroupName="radioGroup" />
</div>
```

`GroupName` attribute make this functionality you need. (If radio1 is `Checked` the radio2 is automatically unchecked.
hope this help:)